# Can't access $scope variable from the outside of function...data allocated when the page load

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

Did not get value for 
`$scope.objectives.length` ..... data to `$scope.objectives` assigned at the time of page load....
it takes value from database...showing output like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: We dont get ya.

Comment: Give `console.log` some time while `$http` request gets result. Its probably console logging before `http` result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

http is asynchronus. it mean that the code executed in success or error will be after some time.

1) USE THEN for http, success is depreceated !
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

2)
when `$http` is done, call a function who use the `$scope.objective` :

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/getObjective'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log("test1"); // this will printed after test2 because http is asynchronus
    $scope.objective = doc ;
    anotherFunction();
}, function errorCallback(response) {

});
console.log("test2");

var anotherFunction = function(){
    console.log($scope.objective.length);
}
```

3) another way is to set a watcher on `$scope.objective`

```
$scope.$watch('objective', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
    console.log(newValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. 'Cannot read property length of undefined' error shows due to not initialization of $scope.objectives variable at first. So initialize this to empty array [] at top.
2. $http.get() is asynchronous function. This means the result or error will be obtained after the response status return back from the server after the succesfull HTTP request.

   ```
   var myApp = angular.module('routingApp');
   myApp.controller('objectiveController', ['$scope', '$http',
   function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.objectives = [];
       $http.get('/getObjective').success(function (doc) {
           $scope.objectives = doc;

           //gets the actual length of result array
           console.log($scope.objectives.length);
       }).error(function (error) {
           console.log('error');
       });

       //get the result 0
       console.log($scope.objectives.length);
   }]);
   ```